# HTTPS Binding exist but fail on reboot. IIS7 dot net 4.0 framework specific

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp.net, .net-4.0, bindings

> ENVIRONMENT

Windows Server 2008 Standard

IIS7

Site1 = asp.net, .net framework 3.5 (2.0) https, IP1 , API, standard ssl certificate

Site2 = asp.net, .net framework 4.0, https, IP2, API, wildcard ssl certificate

Site3 = asp.net, .net framework 4.0, https, IP3, APP, wildcard ssl certificate

Server is set to auto download, install, reboot MS patches.

Please note HTTP to HTTPS redirect is defined in web.config files for SITE2 and SITE3 using this RULE (sorry for poor formatting of XML below):

---

rewrite

rules

rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"

match url="(.*)" />

conditions

add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" /

conditions

action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" /

rule

rules

rewrite

---

I do not think this is related however but added to explain this is why i have not tested access to SITE2 and SITE3 during the outage via HTTP.

> PROBLEM

When the server restart access to SITE1 is ok (https).

When the server restart access to SITE2 is no longer available (https).

When the server restart access to SITE3 is no longer available (https).

Please note all other HTTP sites are ok.

All other HTTPS sites using own IPs and .net 2.0 are ok.

> SOLUTION

Load IIS7

Select SITES

Select SITE2

Select BINDINGS

Remove BINDING NAME "https , SITE1 host header, 443, IP2"

CLOSE

Restart Site

Select BINDINGS

Add BINDING NAME "https , SITE1 host header, 443, IP2" and select certificate.

CLOSE

SITE is then available again.

Repeat for any other effected sites.

> QUESTIONS

I have alerts defined checking each page for availability so its easy to detect, response and resolve this issue .... BUT:

1) Why is it happening ?  (only things different between site1 and site 2/3 are the wildcard certificate, the .net4.0 framework, different IPs and the site 2/3 http to https redirect in the web.config file.

2) How can i resolve this or at least diagnose the issue further?

Application and System Event Logs are are not displaying anything of note.

Thanks for any help

Scott

Answer (score 1):

re add ssl certificate back.

Problem exist when certificate is copy and pasted and NOT imported.

NEVEWR copy and PASTE a SSL certificate.

Thus, II7 SSL will Always restart after you do the following.
:)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply.

Have tried EXPORT / IMPORT via MMC Certificate SNAP IN as opposed to IIS. I believe this will resolve any permission related issues. Will update this post with the results in a month.

> Exporting/Backing up your certificate/Private Key (to .pfx file format)

Start > Run

Type in MMC and click OK

Go into the File Tab > select Add/Remove Snap-in

Click on Certificates and click on Add.

Select Computer Account > Click Next

Select Local Computer > Click Finish

Click OK to close the Add/Remove Snap-in window.

Double click on Certificates (Local Computer) in the center window.

Double click on the Personal folder, and then on Certificates.

Right Click on the Certificate you would like to backup and choose > ALL TASKS > Export

Follow the Certificate Export Wizard to backup your certificate to a .pfx file.

Choose to 'Yes, export the private key'

Choose to "Include all certificates in certificate path if possible." (do NOT select the delete Private Key option)

Enter a password you will remember

Choose to save file on a set location

Finish

You will receive a message > "The export was successful." > Click OK

The .pfx file backup is now saved in the location you selected.

> Importing your Certificate/Private Key (from .pfx file format)

Start > Run

Type in MMC and click OK

Go into the File Tab > select Add/Remove Snap-in

Click on Certificates and click on Add.

Select Computer Account > Click Next

Select Local Computer > Click Finish

Click OK to close the Add/Remove Snap-in window.

Double click on Certificates (Local Computer) in the center window.

Right click on the Personal Certificates Store (folder)

Choose > ALL TASKS > Import

Follow the Certificate Import Wizard to import your Primary Certificate from the .pfx file.

You will need to browse for .pfx files.

Enter the password that was used when exporting the certificate to a .pfx file.

If desired, check the box to "Mark this key as exportable."

When prompted, choose to automatically place the certificates in the certificate stores based on the type of the certificate.

Click Finish to close the certificate wizard.
Close the MMC console.

REF: http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pfx-import-export-iis-7.htm